# BSOD with bitdefender

Tags: windows-10, bsod, bitdefender

I just installed bitdefende total security, but after that when i tried to restart my laptop or put it to sleep i receive blue screen of death with this error:
Driver_Power_State_Failure 
i searched this error on the internet and tried about 10 solution but problem did not solved until i uninstalled the bitdefender and problem solved. i am searching for solution that solve this problem without uninstalling antivirus.

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside/0x9F will give you some insight.  Essentially we would need to see at least the parameters of the bugcheck, but probably a dump.  You can check the Windows Event log for the Bugcheck codes and parameters.  It would be interesting to see the last X to see if they are all the same.

Comment: Try another AV.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed. You can also contact the developer for assistance with their product.